# Retrieving XRDS document in OpenID using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid, google-openid, xrds

I am just playing around with the OpenID protocol. I am trying to send Discovery request and retrieve the XRDS document from google . When I try to do it from the terminal using the curl, I am getting the following output

```
curl --url "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xrds:XRDS xmlns:xrds="xri://$xrds" xmlns="xri://$xrd*($v*2.0)">
      <XRD>
      <Service priority="0">
      <Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server</Type>
      <Type>http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0</Type>
      <Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup</Type>
      <Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon</Type>
      <Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0</Type>
      <URI>https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud</URI>
      </Service>
      </XRD>
    </xrds:XRDS>
```

When I try to do the same from the ruby code, It gives me a 302 error and the url to which it has moved points to the same request url.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Code**

```
  require 'net/http'
  require 'net/https'
  require 'uri'
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

  response =  Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("http://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"))
  puts "#{response.read_body}"
```

How to get the XRDS through the code and why is it showing different outputs. Can someone explain it?Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google expects the https protocol, though in your ruby example you use http, hence the 302 error. The following snippet should get you the xrds document:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)
puts "#{response.read_body}"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, when you fetch the document from ruby, it returns 302 status code, which means that you should look for `location` header and follow it, like curl does.

Another answer suggested just hardcoding the valid url, but that isn't a correct solution, since Google could make it return 302 as well and move the document somewhere else.

Not to mention that you should perform full [Yadis](http://yadis.org) discovery instead of hoping that you'll get an XRDS document from the url (because, for example, Google might decide that it's a good location for explanation of OpenID, and move the XRDS somewhere else using `X-XRDS-Location` header).